# Change CMAKE_C_COMPILER dependent on custom flag set

Tags: cmake

I want to add support of Intel Math Kernel Library to an application. For MKL support I need to change the C compiler to ICC.

I want that to be able set up only one flag `-DMKL_ENABLE=ON`, to change `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` to `icc` as well as to set openMP and Lapack flags and libraries. So I add this lines to the CMakeList.txt:

```
# Enable MKL support?
OPTION(MKL_ENABLE "Enable Intel Mathematical Kernel Library (MKL) support" OFF)

IF(MKL_ENABLE)
  SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "icc" CACHE INTERNAL "Set compiler to icc")
  SET(LAPACK_ENABLE TRUE CACHE INTERNAL "Enable LAPACK libraries from MKL")
  SET(LAPACK_LIBRARIES "-mkl" CACHE INTERNAL "Set LAPACK libraries to -mkl")
  SET(OPENMP_ENABLE ON CACHE INTERNAL "Enable openmp support")
ENDIF(MKL_ENABLE)
```

It seems that all others flags are set and actually work, except `CMAKE_C_COMPILER`, which is still gcc

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.5
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
```

Any ideas how to fix it? It seems CMake setups compiler when `project` is defined. Should I move my section up? Looks not so pretty.

Comment: You have to put those line in front of your `project` command. Have you done so? The C compiler is special for CMake. I would actually advise you, to make it the other way round, once the compiler is detected to be ICC, use also MKL.

Comment: @usr1234567 Yes I did that. It works only before my project definition but not after. It looks like a kluge in CMakeLise.txt, but maybe it is ok.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can move your code before your `project` call. I doubt that code before the `project` call is looking bad. It is also advised to put first `cmake_minimum_required` and then `project`.
2. If you don't like the first way, call `project` with the language `NONE` (leaving it empty would imply C and C++), followed by your code, and finally `enable_language(C)`.
3. Actually, in your case, you should think the other way round: Depending on the found C compiler, you look for MKL and enable it. For CMake the C compiler is crucial, don't play around with it, but reverse your logic. I know, sometimes, these arguments are not valid, depending on the project.

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/project.html

Comment: Thank you, @usrt1234567. I'm not sure about (3). MKL work only with ICC but ICC may be installed without MKL. So if it is MKL, compiler must be icc but not in opposite way.

Comment: Yeah, sure. It should be: Compiler is ICC? => look for MKL => if found, enable. That is how CMake is meant to be used, IMHO.